# Pandas iloc go back n rows and if n is larger than len go back to 0

Tags: python, pandas, slice, series

So let's say I have a series that looks like this:

```
myseries = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
series = pd.Series(myseries)

+---+---+
| 0 | a |
| 1 | b |
| 2 | c |
| 3 | d |
| 4 | e |
| 5 | f |
+---+---+
```

and then I do some basic filtering and want to get the prev n=2 rows like this:

```
idx = series.index[3]
series.iloc[idx-n: idx]

1    b
2    c
dtype: object
```

but if I make n too large like n=5 I get returned an empty series

```
Series([], dtype: object)
```

How could I make it so if my n is too large than it'll just stop at the max n it can go (in this case it would be 3)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to implement a manual check, something like:

```
series.iloc[max(idx-n, 0):idx]
```

On another note, you extract the **index** with `idx = series.index[3]`, so you should have used it with `loc`, not `iloc`.

Comment: wow I didn't even think of using max that way. Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by I should have used loc instead of iloc? I want to get the prev n values. wouldn't iloc work for that since it's indexed sequentially (at least it is in my use case)

Comment: I mean what's the point of `idx=series.index[3]` but not `idx=3`? `series.iloc[idx]` refers to the `idx`-th row, not the row **named** `idx` as how you extracted it.

Comment: Ahh, I see what you're saying now. Thank you for the catch. I misunderstood what iloc and loc does